# Birthdate in Channel Data - how to filter and display age?

Tags: templates, channel-entries

I'm storing birthdates in a Channel field.

1. How do I display the birthdates as age in years? Is that something I just compute in the templates? Or is there a better way?
2. I'm planning to use Low Search. Is there a way I will be able to filter something like "age is 25-30?"

Comment: How are you storing the date in your channel data. Are you using a text field, calendar field, or a third-party date field type?

Comment: Text field. Is there a better option? I want users to just type in something like 1980/01/01. If there are better options, I'm open to them.

Comment: You would definitely want to have it as either a native date field or a third-party date fieldtype so that you can easily pull the dates to calculate the age.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting question. Several options. For display, it should be possible to use a simple calculation plugin and subtract the birthday year from current year, `current_time format="%Y"}` (e.g. 2013 - 1980 == 33). For this to work you probably need the fieldtype to be of the "date" kind for date-formatting to work on the field.

For searching by date, you'll probably need to write a custom query, or use the active record plugin. Because the standard search:field="needle" parameter only works as string. A custom plugin that queries the database is also an option. Fetch the ID's that meet the criteria and feed those to the channel:entries tag `entry_id="13|42|147"`